# Increment Number with AWK

Tags: bash, awk

I have a series of blocks of code with the following pattern:

```
<div class="label label-primary">#1</div>
<!--A1_START-->

  [code block]

<!--A1_END-->
```

The blocks are numbered 1-44.  Block #6, however, has been removed and so I need the numeric value in blocks 7-44 decremented.

How can I use awk to modify the appropriate blocks?  There are dozens of similar questions here on SO, but I can't seem to modify any of them to produce the desired result.

Comment: What you've posted so far is just one description of one block. Post some actual sample input (e.g. 3 or 4 blocks with one missing) and expected output.

Comment: Thanks Ed Morton the code in the blocks is just generic HTML, and the pattern is never repeated inside the block.  The answer provided by fedorqui worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use "strange" field separators, so that the number lies alone and ready to be changed:

```
awk -v FS='<div class="label label-primary">#|</div>' '$2>7{sub($2, $2-1)}1' a
```

#### Explanation

- `-v FS='<div class="label label-primary">#|</div>` set the field separator to either `<div class="label label-primary">#` or `</div>`. This way, the number will be the field 2 (`$2`).
- `$2>7{sub($2, $2-1)}` in case `$2` is bigger than `7`, then replace it with itself minus 1.
- `1` as it is evaluated as True, it performs the default `awk` action: print the current record (line).

#### Test

```
$ cat a
<div class="label label-primary">#1</div>
<!--A1_START-->

  [code block]

<!--A1_END-->

<div class="label label-primary">#2</div>
<!--A1_START-->

  [code block]

<!--A1_END-->

<div class="label label-primary">#10</div>
<!--A1_START-->

  [code block]

<!--A1_END-->
```

And let's run it:

```
$ awk -v FS='<div class="label label-primary">#|</div>' '$2>7{sub($2, $2-1)}1' a
<div class="label label-primary">#1</div>
<!--A1_START-->

  [code block]

<!--A1_END-->

<div class="label label-primary">#2</div>
<!--A1_START-->

  [code block]

<!--A1_END-->

<div class="label label-primary">#9</div>  # <--- 10 is now 9
<!--A1_START-->

  [code block]

<!--A1_END-->
```

Comment: Instead of the sub, using `$2-=1` would suffice.

Comment: @Jidder thanks, it makes sense... but it does not work. I tested and it breaks the line, probably because then it tries to rebuild `$0` and it cannot in the proper format since `FS` was changed.

Comment: Ahh right yeah, so your subbing anything matching `$2` in `$0` not actually $2. Misread, My bad!

Comment: Thanks @fedorqui this worked very well!  Here's the argument that modified the entire document in one pass:  awk -v FS='<div class="label label-primary">#|</div>|<!--A|_START-->|_END-->' '$2>6{sub($2, $2-1)}1' input > output